# Havel-Hakimi algorithm for multi-edge graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

This question is inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259143/is-it-a-valid-chemical) and [this paper](https://piperfw.github.io/degreeSequences/).
In the paper it is claimed that it is possible to use the algorithm so that the resulting graph will always be connected *if* a connected realization exists.

I'm very interested, is it possible somehow to include *multi-edge* realization (keeping connectivity)?
Obviously, we can subtract each iteration not `1`, but other numbers, but how to choose them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.03747.pdf) is the answer:

Theorem 7 (connected loopless multigraph construction).
Let $d$ be a multigraphical
degree sequence, and let us repeatedly select the largest remaining degree vertex and
the smallest non-zero remaining degree vertex, and connect them with a single edge.
This construction procedure results in a connected graph if and only if $d$ was potentially
connected.